# Cant echo php echo as a string

Tags: php

i am trying to echo below. pure text.

```
<script src="<?php echo $config['dir_plugins']; ?>qroll.js"></script>
```

but it wont echo correctly.below is code.somehow it omits the echo as a a string and with it most of the other parts of the string.

```
<?php
$arr = array("qroll", "validate", "hellios");
$str2 = "src='<?php echo \$config[\'dir_plugins\']; ";
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    echo $str2;
    echo $value;
}
?>
```

it just returns `src='`

Comment: Where do you define `$config`

Comment: @RiggsFollyi define it in a seperate file. but i want to echo it as a string. not a variable. used \ thats why on dollar sign

Comment: But you have not included that other file, at least not in the code you are showing us. We can only debug what we see **we are not clairvoyant**

Comment: @RiggsFollyyou dont need to debug. i want $config to be echoed as text. as in if $config = "blue"; i want to echo $config as text not blue.

Comment: What you're looking for is the `eval()` function. Try it and if you have issue, post your attempt here

Comment: Surely `$config`  has to be an array

Comment: I presume from your comments on the first answer that you actually want to echo a string that includes `<?php` as text rather than actually processing this in PHP?

Comment: Try `$str2 = "src='/$config/dir_plugins/";` is that what you want

Comment: @MartinParkin yes

Comment: First, if you don't want php to interpret your strings, use single quote (') instead of double quotes ("). Second, do you print your output in a browser instead of a terminal ?

Comment: Do a view source on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from some comments, it appears that the user acutally wants to echo a string that includes some PHP in it.

If the desired output is:

```
src='<?php echo $config['dir_plugins']; ?>
```

Change your code to:

```
$str2 = "src='&lt;?php echo \$config['dir_plugins']; ?&gt;";
```

This will output:

```
src='<?php echo $config['dir_plugins']; ?>
```

Presumably the rest of the output (the script name and script tags) will be added by your code.

You are in effect escaping the HTML-incompatible parts of your output by converting `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;`

Comment: Thank you that works perfect. And thanks for the explanation XD

Answer (score 1):

This line is strange:

```
$str2 = "src='<?php echo \$config[\'dir_plugins\']; ";
```

I think it should be

```
$str2 = "src='".$config[\'dir_plugins\']."'";
```

Comment: yes i know you can remove echo and call $config. but i dont want that. i want the whole php echo as string. pure text

Comment: And the backslashes should be forward slashes

Comment: You don't need any slashes inside `$config[...]` because you don't need to escape this any more with your solution.

Comment: @MartinParkin i need to escape because i dont want $config as a variable but text

Comment: but in this case you haven't closed the opening `<?php`... at the end of that string-to-be (I am not sure if it would work then, but still)

Comment: maybe you should try to use html entities instead of `<`, `>` , `$` and the quotes inside the "string"

Comment: @Johannes i would. but i need to loop through the array.

Answer (score 1):

This does what I think you are asking for

```
<?php
$arr = array("qroll", "validate", "hellios");
$str2 = '<script src="<?php echo $config[\'dir_plugins\']; ?>"';
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    echo $str2 . $value . '.js></script>';
    //echo PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

OUTPUT

```
<script src="<?php echo $config['dir_plugins']; ?>"qroll.js></script>
<script src="<?php echo $config['dir_plugins']; ?>"validate.js></script>
<script src="<?php echo $config['dir_plugins']; ?>"hellios.js></script>
```

Comment: it does. my mistake i did not take into account the html tags. thank you

Answer (score 0):

To avoid PHP evaluating a string, do not use `"` but `'`

```
$str2 = 'src=\'<?php echo $config[\'dir_plugins\']; ';
```

should do the trick

Note that if you didnt set the page as `text/plain` your browser will hide everything after the `<?` because of the `<` . You may want to use the `&lt;` to force it to be printed for debug purpose.

Comment: this gives me just src=' for some reason

Comment: Actually you echo everything but your browser hide the data because of the `<` (look as the source code of the page)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to echo HTML code for display on your page, you can always try [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) which will convert `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;` for you.

```
<?php
$arr = array("qroll", "validate", "hellios");
$str2 = "src='<?php echo \$config[\'dir_plugins\']; ";
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($str2);
    echo $value;
}
```

Output in source:

```
src='&lt;?php echo $config[\'dir_plugins\']; qrollsrc='&lt;?php echo $config[\'dir_plugins\']; validatesrc='&lt;?php echo $config[\'dir_plugins\']; hellios
```

Output on page:

```
src='<?php echo $config[\'dir_plugins\']; qrollsrc='<?php echo $config[\'dir_plugins\']; validatesrc='<?php echo $config[\'dir_plugins\']; hellios
```

---

```
<?php
$str2 = 'src=\'<?php echo $config[\'dir_plugins\']; ?>\'';
echo htmlspecialchars($str2);
```

Output on page:

```
src='<?php echo $config['dir_plugins']; ?>'
```

---

Here is an example of everything together:

```
<pre>
<?php
$arr = array('qroll', 'validate', 'hellios');
$str2 = '<script src=\'<?php echo $config[\'dir_plugins\']; ?>';
$str3 = '.js\'></script>';
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($str2), $value, htmlspecialchars($str3), "\n";
}
?>
</pre>
```

Which will look like this on your page:

```
<script src='<?php echo $config['dir_plugins']; ?>qroll.js'></script>
<script src='<?php echo $config['dir_plugins']; ?>validate.js'></script>
<script src='<?php echo $config['dir_plugins']; ?>hellios.js'></script>
```